# Stack up multiple filter queries in mongoengine

Tags: django, mongoengine

How is it possible to run the following:

```
someQuerySet.filter(keyword='someKey')
someQuerySet.filter(keyword='someOtherKey')
```

I get `InvalidQueryError: Duplicate query conditions` whenever I try to do that. I know it's possible to filter by a list of values, but right now, I need to do individual filters.

Later edit: 
I'm actually using:

```
someQuerySet.filter(keyword__ne='someKey')
someQuerySet.filter(keyword__ne='someOtherKey')
```

Comment: By individual filters do you mean on separate lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could build up Q objects like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

filters = Q(keyword='someKey')
…
filters = filters | Q(keyword='someOtherKey')

someQuerySet.filter(filters)
```

This will basically create a `WHERE` clause like this: `WHERE keyword = 'someKey' OR keyword = 'someOtherKey'`

I am doing this from memory, so let me know if this doesn't work, and I will look into some of my past code.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the error is because by default the queries parameters AND.  So you are asking for `keyword="SomeKey" AND keyword="SomeOtherKey"` which can never be true.

You could use `Q` objects to or like: http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html#advanced-queries or do a `$in` where the value matches any in a list eg: `keyword__in=["SomeKey", "SomeOtherKey"]`

Comment: My mistake, I was actually using keyword__ne='SomeKey" and keyword__ne="SomeOtherKey". This example should be true...

Comment: try `nin` instead http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/guide/querying.html?highlight=nin#query-operators

Comment: @ross These links are broken